# How much time does "let" really save in RSpec tests?

Tags: rspec, performance-testing, rspec-rails, let

I find it much easier to just set a variable in my code than use `let`.  `let` is finicky and always tells me ways in which I'm using it wrong.

When I use a simple variable declaration in my specs like

`tx_good = makeTransaction1()`      , everything works fine.

But when I use `let` like so

`let(:tx_good) { makeTransaction1() }`  I will invariably get some error like this telling me it can't go here or there...

```
  `let` and `subject` declarations are not intended to be called
   in a `before(:context)` hook, as they exist to define state that
   is reset between each example, while `before(:context)` exists to
   define state that is shared across examples in an example group.
```

Given how finicky using `let` is, I'm forced to wonder is it worth the extra effort and care I must put forward to use it.  Does anyone know how much processing time is really saved using let vs. merely assigning a variable up front?

I want to follow good testing protocol, so I'm hoping someone can convince me of why I should use `let` like (seemingly) everyone else does.

Comment: let's give a way to share code and dependencies are lazily evaluated and threadsafe.  From your example, you're not using them correctly - so I would try them out before you dismiss them.

Comment: second @Anthony  I was similarly frustrated with `let` once upon a time, it's a little confusing because it seems like you are declaring variables outside your tests.  you can put `let` inside a `describe` or `context` block, but not inside an `it` or `before` block.  Basically this creates a reusable variable that is created new for each test, which helps prevent database artifacts between tests and has the added benefit of lazy loading which only creates the variable once it's called.  This can create seemingly 'finicky' behavior, but it's really doing what it's supposed to. : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using this stuff wrong, and I understand your frustration. So let me give you a condensed manual for using `let`s in RSpec.

Main value in using `let` does not come from saved processing power. It integral part of the wider RSpec philosophy. I'll try to explain and hopefully it'll be easier for you to progress...

## `let` is lazy

whatever you define inside the block will be called if and only if it is actually used in the spec:

```
context do
  let(:foo) { sleep(10000) } # will not happen
  specify { expect(1).to eq(1) }
end 

context do 
  specify do 
     foo = sleep(10000) # you'll wait
     expect(1).to eq(1)
  end
end
```

Use `let!`, which is eager (i.e. not lazy) version of `let`

## `let` is memoized

Whatever is defined inside the block will happen only once (in the scope of the context):

```
context do
  let(:random_number) { rand }
  specify do
    expect(random_number).to eq(random_number) # will always pass
  end
end
```

If you don't want this feature, define a method:

```
context do
  def random_number
    rand
  end
  specify do
    expect(random_number).to eq(random_number) # sometimes pass, mostly fail
  end
end
```

## `let` in lower level contexts overwrites `let` definitions from higher level:

```
context do
   let(:x) { 1 }
   specify { expect(x).to eq(1) # pass

   context 'with different x' do 
     let(:x) { 2 }
     specify { expect(x).to eq(2) # pass
   end

   context do
     specify { expect(x).to eq(1) # pass
   end
end
```

^ this allows you to compose the specs in a way, where only relevant "pieces" of the setup is mentioned in the context, for example:

```
context do 
   let(:x) { 1 }
   let(:y) { 1 }
   let(:z) { 1 }
   specify { expect(foo(x, y, z)).to eq(3) }

   context 'when z is nil'
     let(:z) { nil }
     specify { expect(foo(x, y, z)).to raise_error) } # foo doesn't work with z = nil
   end

   context 'when x is nil'
     let(:x) { nil }
     specify { expect(foo(x, y, z)).to eq(15) } 
   end
end
```

## Bonus: `subject` is a magic `let`

```
# writing 
subject { foo(x) }
# is almost the same as writing 
let(:subject) { foo(x) }
```

`subject` is a reserved concept in RSpec, it's a "thing you test" so you could write the example with `foo(x, y, z) like this:

```
context do 
   let(:x) { 1 }
   let(:y) { 1 }
   let(:z) { 1 }
   subject { foo(x, y, z) }
   specify { expect(subject).to eq(3) }

   context 'when z is nil'
     let(:z) { nil }
     specify { expect(subject).to raise_error) } # foo doesn't work with z = nil
   end

   context 'when x is nil'
     let(:x) { nil }
     specify { expect(foo(subject)).to eq(15) } 
   end
end
```

## Regarding the error you have...

> `let` and `subject` declarations are not intended to be called    in
>   a `before(:context)` hook, as they exist to define state that    is
>   reset between each example, while `before(:context)` exists to
>   define state that is shared across examples in an example group.

you're doing something like

```
before do
  let(:x) { ... }
end
```

just don't do it, you define `let` inside `describe` and `context`, but you can use them (not define them, use what is defined) inside `before` and `specify`:

```
let(:name) { 'Frank' }
before do
  User.create name: name
end

specify do
   expect(User.where(name: name).count).to eq(1)
end
```

Comment: great well thought out explanation, should be accepted

Comment: Ah, so `let` is useful for setting up different scenarios to test without changing the state of a shared variable in a way that could break those other tests.  Kind of like passing a variable to a small function and creating it's own scope I think.  It also seems to cut down on the need for new variable names since we can reuse the same symbol in different contexts.

Comment: also note the one-liner syntax allows you to replace "expect(subject)" with "is_expected" or replace "expect(subject).to" with "should"

e.g., subject { 3 }; it { should eq(3) }; it { is_expected.to eq(3) }