# Rspec tests not updating save! from action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

In my Rspec tests are checking to see if my JWT secret has rotated. However, my tests are failing because the JWT token has not rotated in my test but it has in my code.

```
expect(Jwt.verify(token, user.jwt_secret)).to eq(true) # <--- Passes
headers = { AUTHORIZATION: "JWT " + token }
post("/logout", headers: headers) # <--- calls logout action
expect(Jwt.verify(token, user.jwt_secret)).to eq(false) # <--- still returns true instead of expected false
```

I've verified that my code rotates and saves the new JWT secret but it's not rotating in my tests. Is there something I am missing in my tests?

```
  def logout
    current_user.rotate_jwt!
  end
```

Comment: i think you need to call `user.reload` to refresh user in spec before call expect, since current_user in controller is not user in spec although both point to the same record on db

Comment: Even if rotate_jwt changes something in the db  you still need to call reload since rails caches the query result the first time you call user.jwt_secret

Comment: The reason it happens is `let` and `subjects` are memorized, please check this explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53964513/299774

Answer (score 0):

Unit tests should only test explicitly what's happening within the code. I would suggest that all you care about with the `logout` test is that current user receives `:rotate_jwt`. Then write a User unit test that tests the functionality of `rorate_jwt`

Something like

```
it "calls rotate_jwt! on the current user" do
  allow(user).to receive(:rotate_jwt!).and_return(true) # don't actually call the method
  expect(user).to receive(:rotate_jwt!)

  post("/logout", headers: headers)
end
```

All your code is doing is calling a method on the `User`. test that only.